# Mysqldump returning empty file

Tags: php, mysql

My script is as following:

```
<?php

$database = 'database';
$user = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$filename = 'database_backup_'.date( 'd-m-Y-h:i:s' ).'.sql';

$result = exec( 'mysqldump '.$database.' --password='.$password.' --user='.$user.' --single-transaction >/some-path/backups/'.$filename, $output );

?>
```

This script is creating a file but it is empty.

Comment: Maybe it's getting an error. Try redirecting stderr to a file to see the error.

Comment: Are you running the script from the web or CLI?

Comment: @Barmar, I am running it from the web

Comment: Then you need to redirect stderr to a file so you can view it. If you run it from the CLI the error messages will show on your terminal.

Comment: I'm using this `https://www.webslesson.info/2018/02/backup-mysql-database-using-php.html`